# Deploying a c-compiled ruby gem with puppet module

Tags: puppet, ruby, gem

I have a type/provider module that depends on a c-compiled gem. What is the best way to package this up and deploy to the users? Is the SOP to install the gem as a package (using gem provider) first, then I can make use of the module? Or is there a way to include it as part of the lib and use it straight away?

Context: We are creating a fully fleshed out perforce module. We are having issues getting the marshalled data to correctly load into an array of dictionaries and would rather use the the vendor-compiled gem instead.

Comment: Another note - We are on puppet 6, and the p4ruby @ rubygems only supports up to ruby 2.4 (need 2.5 or greater). So I cannot just add it to the gemfile (unless there is another way to do it there).

Comment: well, the gems have dependencies, that's exactly what you shuldn't do. You need to update (upgrade) the whole tree of dependencies, or acknowledge the vendor doesn't support your version, and find a workaround. If you compiled yourself (for 2.5) than, that's fine, and you can install gem manually or setup your own repository (using Nexus, Artifactory or straight apache/nginx) and have the Distribution managed by yourself.